# IF was not expected this time

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

```
@rem videodir webm -> mp4
@rem audio acc video h264 overwrite optional

set /p videodir="directory>>> "
echo %videodir%
FOR %%i IN (%videodir%) DO %%~di
cd %videodir%
pause
set /p option="turn on overwrite? [y/n]>>> "
echo %option%
pause
IF %option%==y (
FOR /R %videodir% %%i IN (*.webm) DO ( ffmpeg -i "%%i" -y -c:a aac -c:v libx264 "%videodir%\mp4\%%~ni.mp4" )
) IF %option%==n (
FOR /R %videodir% %%i IN (*.webm) DO ( ffmpeg -i "%%i" -n -c:a aac -c:v libx264 "%videodir%\mp4\%%~ni.mp4" )
) ELSE (
echo "invaild value" )

pause
```

`If` statement keeps making error. please help me sir.

I tried to convert both `D:\school.webm` `C:\school3.webm` file into mp4, but whether i turn on or off overwrite option, it just keeps raising error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
) IF %option%==n (
```

should be

```
) else IF %option%==n (
```

Additionally, better syntax is `if /i "%option%"=="y"` which provides some protection against an entry like  `y hello` and `/i` allows a case-insensitive match.

It would also be a good idea to use the `search` facility to find out about `choice` and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statements parenthesized blocks are an overkill, you have a single command so no need to enclose them in parenthesis, in fact no need for `else` either.
To directly fix you error, simply put  `IF %option%==n (` on a new line.. that's it.

I'll however encourage you to use `choice` for these... choice like scripts, that what it is built for:

```
@echo off
rem videodir webm -> mp4
rem audio acc video h264 overwrite optional

set /p videodir="directory>>> "
pushd "%videodir%">nul 2>&1 || (echo no such dir "%videodir%" & exit /b 1)
choice /M "Overwrite?"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 set "opt=y"
if %errorlevel% equ 2 set "opt=n"

for /R %videodir% %%i in (*.webm) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -%opt% -c:a aac -c:v libx264 "%videodir%\mp4\%%~ni.mp4"
popd
```